# PowerBI DAX - Sum table by criteria and date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

relatively new to PowerBI/PowerQuery/DAX and have become stuck at the following problem. I am unsure what road to go down to get the best outcome and would appreciate any help.

My data table is connected to a time tracking application. A **User** will enter a time entry everytime they complete a task. The task can be either a **Project** task or an **Admin** task. When selecting either of these, there will be multiple sub-categories beneath each, each with its own ID. This translates to my table as the following :

```
User    ProjectID    AdminID    Hours    Date
John    1                       2        01/01/22
John                 11         1        01/01/22
John    4                       1        01/01/22
John                 12         3        01/01/22
John                 13         1        01/01/22
Pete                 7          1        01/01/22
Pete    2                       4        01/01/22
Pete    3                       2        01/01/22
Mike    1                       6        01/01/22
Mike                 9          1        01/01/22
Mike                 10         1        01/01/22
```

My objective is, for each **Date** in the table, to calculate the total hours spent either doing **Project** tasks or **Admin** tasks. I am not concerned about the specific breakdown (ie the sum of the unique IDs), rather the overall total. The above example covers just one day, in reality my data covers multiple years. My expected output will look like this :

```
User    TotalProject    TotalAdmin    Date
John    3               5             01/01/22
John    3               4             01/02/22
John    5               2             01/03/22
Pete    5               1             01/01/22
Pete    1               8             01/02/22
Pete    6               2             01/03/22
Mike    6               2             01/01/22 
Mike    6               1             01/02/22
Mike    7               2             01/03/22
```

I am unsure the best method to achieve this - either by creating some kind of column in the table through PowerQuery? Or a calculated column using DAX? And if so, what the SUM syntax would look like?

Very willing to learn, to any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your input dates are all 01/01/22 and don't equate to your output dates. Your hours don't add up either. Can you post example input and desired output for the sample input.

Comment: @ScottCee you need to create measures to define your intended result. Calculated columns are not a good DAX practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sample input, just create 2 measures.

```
Total Admin = CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[Hours]), NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[AdminID])))

Total Project = CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[Hours]), NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[ProjectID])))
```

[image]